# Changing the name after choosing a location

Tags: flutter, dart, maps

I need to solve my problem.
I have a ElevatedButton which is called 'location' and calls google maps . I would like that when I select a location on map (specifically the city) and save it the text of name ElevationButton to change from 'location' to name of marked city: [first step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGuwq.png)[second step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7Y6J.png)[third step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsCYi.png)

I tryed find solution on different ways but there is no solution of my problem

Just ElevatedButton:

```
ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          side: const BorderSide(width: 1),
          minimumSize: const Size(342, 45),
        ),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const MapLocation(),
        )),
        child: const Text('Lokalizacja'),
```

MAP:

```
    class MapLocation extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapLocation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MapLocation> createState() => MapLocationState();
}

class MapLocationState extends State<MapLocation> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller =
      Completer<GoogleMapController>();

  TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();

  Set<Marker> _markers = Set<Marker>();

  static const CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(51.110182, 17.032035),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _setMarker(LatLng(51.110182, 17.032035));
  }

  void _setMarker(LatLng point) {
    setState(
      () {
        _markers.add(
          Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId('marker'),
            position: point,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Lokalizacja'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _searchController,
                    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                    decoration:
                        InputDecoration(hintText: 'Wyszukaj miejscowość'),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      var place = await LocationService()
                          .getPlace(_searchController.text);
                      _goToPlace(place);
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.search))
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: GoogleMap(
                myLocationEnabled: true,
                mapType: MapType.terrain,
                markers: _markers,
                initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                  _controller.complete(controller);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat);
  }

  Future<void> _goToPlace(Map<String, dynamic> place) async {
    final double lat = place['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    final double lng = place['geometry']['location']['lng'];

    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(target: LatLng(lat, lng), zoom: 12),
      ),
    );

    _setMarker(LatLng(lat, lng));
  }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? add your code